# Clear Bitmap data and make it null

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to Clear my Bitmap data. The scenario is that I am taking a screen capture of an Widget(Imageview) and I am storing it in a Bitmap. This action comes in a Button click. SO after some time I get a Memory error. So I want to clear the values in the bitmap. So to do that I have done the following code :
The BitMap variable is mCaptureImageBitmap

```
  public void ButtonClick(View v)
    {
               mCaptureImageBitmap.recycle();   
               mCaptureImageBitmap=null;                        
                View ve = findViewById(R.id.mainscreenGlViewRelativeLayout);
                ve.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                mCaptureImageBitmap = ve.getDrawingCache();
    }
```

But I get an error of NullPoint exception. Please help me

Comment: in which line do you get Null Pointer?

Answer (score 1):

You have most of the right code but in the wrong order. Try doing something like this

```
public void ButtonClick(View v)
{
      Bitmap mCaptureImageBitmap;
      final View ve = findViewById(R.id.mainscreenGlViewRelativeLayout);
      ve.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      mCaptureImageBitmap = ve.getDrawingCache();

      // Do something useful with your image here

      mCaptureImageBitmap.recycle();
      mCaptureImageBitmap = null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ...

```
ve.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  

// Add these lines 

ve.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),              MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)); 
ve.layout(0, 0, ve.getMeasuredWidth(), ve.getMeasuredHeight());   
ve.buildDrawingCache(true); 

Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ve.getDrawingCache()); 

mCaptureImageBitmap = b;

ve.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false); // clear drawing cache
```